# Default user profile getting filled with temp ie files

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

I have several Windows Server 2003 Terminal servers to service our domain users.
Sometimes the Default User profile (C:\Documents and Settings\Default User) gets filled with tempoary internet files, so when a new user logs in, he gets a 1GB profile (instead of 20MB) that fills up the server fast.

Why is it the default user profile gets filled up with files like that, by who and how do i prevent this?

Comment: What security principals have write access to C:\Documents and Settings\Default User?

Comment: Are you sure that someone on the network doesn't have virus/malware? http://blog.sat0ri.com/malware/2009/07/default-user-temporary-internet-file-weirdness/

Comment: Only system and administrators have write access to that folder.

Comment: I tryed to google some of the tempoary internet files, and it looks like it is Symantec update files. 

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH166279

Symantec antivirus runs as "Local System" service

damn, why is it placings its files in that folder on a TS server. thats bad.